# FastCGI with LIGHTTPD in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am currently trying to set up lighttpd server together with fastcgi enabled and in python language. However I have faced this error and after hours of googling, I cant seem to find a solution to it and I do not know what's causing the error as I am fairly new into this. Do take a look, and I hope that you will be able to help me! Thank you so much and have a nice day!

Important Details:
Operating system --> Fedora
Python version --> 3.9.4

The error I faced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/lighttpd/conf.d/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    WSGIServer(myapp).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi.py", line 111, in run
    sock = self._setupSocket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1025, in _setupSocket
    sock = socket.fromfd(FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO, socket.AF_INET,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/socket.py", line 545, in fromfd
    return socket(family, type, proto, nfd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
```

My python file, directory : /etc/lighttpd/conf.d/test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
def myapp(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello World!\n']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer(myapp).run()
```

My fastcgi config file in directory: /etc/lighttpd/conf.d/fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi.server = (
    ".py" =>
    (
        "python-fcgi" =>
        (
         "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/socketsfastcgi.python.socket",
         "bin-path" => "test.py",
         "check-local" => "disable",
         "max-procs" => 1,
        )
    ))
```

In my /var/run/lighttpd, theres a file socketsfastcgi.python.socket-0

(i tried to change my socket path to incorporate the -0 to become "/var/run/lighttpd/socketsfastcgi.python.socket-0" and it created a file socketsfastcgi.python.socket-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

On a Fedora system, things worked for me (I could not reproduce your issue) after I did a `pip install flup`, as I did not have that available on my Fedora 34 test system.

Check your environment to make sure you have not overridden python package locations and accidentally pointed to python2 packages.

BTW: you should prefer to use a full path in `"bin-path"`, e.g. `"bin-path" => "/path/to/test.py"`

FYI: depending on max-procs, lighttpd creates sockets with `-0`, `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, etc suffixes on the `"socket"` since the sockets must be named uniquely.  What you specify in `"socket"` path does not need the `-0` suffix, as you found.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the reply! May I ask how do I check my environment to ensure that I have not overridden my python package locations?

Comment: `env | grep PYTHON`

Comment: Hello @gstrauss, I realise when I issue that command, there's no output, could that be the reason why it isn't working? would you be able to give me your assistance?

Comment: No output suggests that you have not overridden the paths in the environment, which is good, because you should not do that unless you know what you are doing.  As to your second question, I must confess that no, I won't be able to help you further.  Simplify things as much as you can and try to get something simple working.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI